# Pode colocar outras tags dentro de uma tag 'ul'?

Tags: html, html-tags, semântica

Eu posso inserir outras tags do [html](/questions/tagged/html) dentro da tag `<ul>`?

Por exemplo:

```
<ul>
 <li>
   Lorem ipsum dolor...
 </li>

 <hr>

 <li>
   Lorem ipsum dolor...
 </li>

 <hr>

 <li>
   Lorem ipsum dolor...
 </li>
</ul>
```

Gostaria de saber se é semanticamente correto?

Comment: dentro da `<ul>` deve exisitr `<li>`, lá sim pode colocar outras tags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Sim**, mas não é qualquer elemento.

Tanto `<ul>` quanto `<ol>`, aceitam apenas:

- `<li>`
- `<script>` (Script-supporting)
- `<template>` (Script-supporting)

Como está na no WHATWG HTML Living Standard:

- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element

  > Modelo de conteúdo:
  >
  > Nenhum elemento, um ou mais **li** e elementos **script-supporting**.
- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#script-supporting-elements-2

  > Elementos **script-supporting** são aqueles que não representam nada
  > por si mesmos (ou seja, eles não são renderizados), mas são usados
  > para dar suporte a scripts, por exemplo para fornecer funcionalidade
  > para o usuário.
  >
  > Os seguintes elementos são elementos de **Script-supporting**:
  >
  > - `script`, `template`

Se tentar adicionar um elemento não aceito o motor DOM irá renderizar normal para a maioria dos casos, mas o comportamento, dependendo do motor ou se for um navegador mais antigo, pode ser afetado/rearranjado, o que irá causar mais diferenças inesperadas, o melhor é seguir as normas.

Usar uma tag errada ou em local errado **não irá afetar o SEO**, você pode até usar só com elementos `<div>` ao invés de tags como `<header>`, `<main>` e `<section>`, **isso não vai piorar o SEO**, os buscadores não tem um padrão exato, estão sempre em evolução, mas é sempre PRIORIZANDO o conteúdo e NÃO a estrutura HTML.

Answer (score -1):

Sim!

Você pode, porém existem tags especificas, tag `<ul>` ou `<ol>`, aceitam `<li>` e `<script>`.

Abaixo, tem a documentação de cada tag `ul` ou `ol`

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).